# Are questions about screenplay on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I suppose writers is mostly for people writing novels and books in general but are questions about screenplays on-topic? Screenplays for TV shows, movies, theatre and video games

Comment: Related: [Are questions about brainstorming scripts for video on-topic?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2067/11428)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Writers!

Questions about screenplays are on-topic and they even have a tag, [screenwriting](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenwriting), with (at present) 50 questions.  I think all the questions so far are about TV, movie, and theatre, though I don't see why game scripts wouldn't also be on-topic so long as they focus on the script-writing aspect and not the game-play or rules aspect.  Games are different from the others in that there are multiple paths through the script depending on player decisions, and it seems like there are some interesting plotting and event-management challenges there.  So, ask away!

Comment: If questions about games go into design or execution, we can always send them to the [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site.